# TS cannot find module from node_modules when importing an image

Tags: typescript, leaflet

I have the following piece of code within my .tsx file:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import iconShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';
```

And Typescript is complaining about the 2nd and 3rd line. Not only the linter, but the TS compiler itself.

Specifically the linter says that "It cannot find module 'blabla/icon.png' or its corresponding type declarations. However, importing L is ok.

Anyone has any idea why this is happening and how to solve this?

My tsconfig file looks like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",        // path to output directory
      "sourceMap": true,          // allow sourcemap support
      "strictNullChecks": true,   // enable strict null checks as a best practice
      "module": "esnext",         // specify module code generation
      "jsx": "react",             // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
      "target": "es5",            // specify ECMAScript target version
      "allowJs": true,             // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "paths": {
    }
  },
  "include" : ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "config", ".vscode"]
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, apparently it is the same as I mentioned below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by creating an index.d.ts file with the following content:

```
declare module '*.png';
```

Comment: God! I was put this code in some file that I already have, so it wasn't work.
When I created a new file with this code, everything work

Comment: React noob here, where do I put / reference it? (index.d.ts)

Comment: In root folder of the project

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Because the [`import` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) works only for [JS modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and (this should be obvious) an image file is not a JS module.

Because importing modules and module bundlers have quite some history, there are hacks to make static assets look like JS modules (see e.g. https://github.com/rollup/awesome#other-file-imports). It is possible to configure a bundling toolchain in such a way that a CSS assets looks like a JS module, and said JS module is actually JS code that runs (and its effect is to append the wrapped CSS asset into a document body).

It's possible to apply such hacks to image assets, but since the semantics are not standardized, the behaviour will depend on how your toolchain is configured (e.g. compare [@rollup/plugin-url](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/url), [@rollup/plugin-image](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/image), [rollup-plugin-file-as-blob](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/rollup-plugin-file-as-blob), [rollup-plugin-imagemin](https://github.com/malchata/rollup-plugin-imagemin) and [rollup-plugin-smart-asset](https://github.com/sormy/rollup-plugin-smart-asset) , all of which allow to `import` image assets but with wildly varying behaviour... and that's just for Rollup-based toolchains, I'm not even considering webpack, parcel or others here).

> ...and how to solve this?

Do not import image assets as if they were JS code, and be mindful of your toolchain.

Comment: Your answer seems to be very focused on JS, however this is Typescript. I am just saying because for example I have also a JS file that imports an image just like that and it works. On top of that, if I ignore the TS error it also works.

Comment: I just found the answer, please, see my response down below.